# Angular JS Error: error:areq Bad Argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<body  data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <div class="container">


        Name:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />{{name}}

        <br/>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope)
        {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'Joe', city: 'Seattle'},
                { name: 'Jack', city: 'Dallas'},
                { name: 'Jason', city: 'Houston'}
            ];
        }       
    </script>               
</body>
```

I was following a tutorial video on Youtube. 
I checked several times still couldn't find any problem.
The error is "https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=SimpleController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined"
Please help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Version of angular ?

Comment: It's not a problem of the version... the code shown here works fine.

Comment: Yes it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/xqovx7xu/

Comment: @m59 so what might be the problem for OP ?

Comment: @squiroid no idea, this question should be closed. Whatever the problem is doesn't appear to be within this post.

Comment: I am closing this question as it is not clear what OP is asking :-P

Comment: I added two screen shot....

Comment: the code was working fine until I removed the ng-init and added the ng-controller.............

Answer (score 0):

you need assign view to a controller in the template so that the view can render the scope data

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'Joe', city: 'Seattle'},
                { name: 'Jack', city: 'Dallas'},
                { name: 'Jason', city: 'Houston'}
            ];
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
 <div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">


        Name:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />{{name}}

        <br/>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```